# No GUI opens when run

Tags: java, user-interface

Out of nowhere when I run my application no GUI pops up only says BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second) in the console, don't know why it happened or if anyone has had this before? Tried restarting netbeans etc ill post my code below incase its that. And it was working at one point.

pastebin(dot)com/XvD30sCP code is here

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: Sounds like the code to run the GUI is not called... Or, are you also running? or only compiling?

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

 global_crime gc = new global_crime();
 gc.setVisible(true);
 }
```

Add this... it will work now..